# Docker container CentOs with Apache

Tags: apache, docker, centos7

I'm toying around with Docker. But i have an issue with Docker when trying to build a Centos and Apache Server in a container. I run Docker on my Windows 10 Machine.
The CentOS + Apache container, is coupled with a Maria DB image.

When i do the docker-compose my Apache container starts and imediateliy shut down with exit code 0.

Here's my dockerfile :

```
FROM centos:centos7
LABEL Author = "Aurelien H."
LABEL Description = "DOCKERFILE : Allows the creation of a Container with a Centreon distribution installed via packages"

#Update and install requirements
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y wget nano centos-release-scl httpd git

#Install Centreon repo
RUN cd /usr/local/src
RUN wget http://yum.centreon.com/standard/3.4/el7/stable/noarch/RPMS/centreon-release-3.4-4.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y --nogpgcheck centreon-release-3.4-4.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

#Install Centreon
RUN yum install -y centreon-base-config-centreon-engine centreon centreon-pp-manager
RUN yum clean all
#RUN systemctl enable httpd.service
#RUN systemctl start httpd.service
EXPOSE  80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Here's my docker compose.

```
centreon:
  build: ./centreon
  ports:
    - "80:80"
#  volumes:
#    - "./data"
  links:
   - mariadb
mariadb:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notR00tPassword
```

Comment: try `CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-DFOREGROUND"]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Still have this message : 
trainingdocker_centreon   "/bin/bash"              22 seconds ago      Exited (0) 22 seconds ago

Comment: The issue i encounter is not from the docker file but from the Docker compose.

Comment: I solved by forcing rebuild of my image when executing the docker compose. I had an issue with Docker's cache.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use the "docker-compose up --build" command.
It rebuild the images before executing them.
Problem solved.